# How can I disable a view behind my SlidingDrawer in Android?

Tags: android, view, clickable, slidingdrawer

I have a SlidingDrawer that pops up from the bottom of the screen and fills the screen about 80%. Even though the SlidingDrawer view is in focus, it is still possible to click on items, buttons and other elements in the view that is behind the SlidingDrawer. When SlidingDrawer is active/pulled up/in focus, I want to disable the entire view behind it so it will not be able to recieve clicks and touches. Is there a good way to disable an entire view? I have tried setEnable(false) and setClickable(false) but neither of them work.

Help?

Comment: I use sliding drawer too but never had this problem^^

Comment: Did you figure this one out? Having the same problem.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5393314/android-slidingdrawer-doesnt-disable-buttons-under-the-drawer?lq=1

Comment: use this : - http://stackoverflow.com/a/31587294/4395114

Answer (score 13):

Here's a way to get around this problem (I needed a solution also) - grab the linearLayout that holds the contents and add a click listener.  Have the click listener respond to clicks (throw away, whatever) - and this then stops it propagating to the view below the sliding drawer - it works for me - and it doesn't block the other items in the drawer.

Comment: This amounts to what @mansukh says below - but his way is less code.

Answer (score 3):

In side Layout do   `android:clickable="true"`

For Example Following file is `drawer.xml`

Inside `LinearLayout` `android:id="@+id/drawer_view"` `clickable="true"`

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".MainActivity">


        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

        </FrameLayout>      

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/drawer_view"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/navigation_drawer_width"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:background="@color/drawer_background">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:background="@drawable/order_list_selector"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/user_image_w_h"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/user_image_w_h"
                    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                    android:id="@+id/drawerUserImage"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_user_icon"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:padding="5dp">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/drawerUserNameTextView"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Mansukh Ahir"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/font_large" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/drawerEmailIdTextView"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/font_very_small"/>
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>

            <View
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                android:background="@color/holo_gray_light" />

            <ListView
                android:id="@+id/drawerListSlideMenu"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
                android:dividerHeight="1dp" />
        </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: To my mind this is the easiest and most direct solution to layouts that 'cover' each other - this makes the background of the covering page 'absorb' the click as opposed to passing it down.

Comment: because i can't override `SwipeRefreshLayout` method `canChildScrollUp()` thats why i use this solution.

Answer (score 2):

Joe's answer did not do the trick for me. My scenario is a bit diferent. I have a FrameLayout with two children. Only one of the children has to be 'active' at a given moment, and while the second is active the first should no longer process any input. My solution:

```
    public static void changeVGstate(ViewGroup current, boolean enable)
{
    current.setFocusable(enable);
    current.setClickable(enable);
    current.setEnabled(enable);

    for (int i = 0; i < current.getChildCount(); i++)
    {
        View v = current.getChildAt(i); 
        if (v instanceof ViewGroup)
            changeVGstate((ViewGroup)v, enable);
        else
        {
            v.setFocusable(enable);
            v.setClickable(enable);
            v.setEnabled(enable);
        }
    }
}
```

Enjoy!

Answer (score 2):

I've tried to put `SlidingDrawer` in the `RelativeLayout`, instead of `LinearLayout`. And set
`mySlidingDrawer.bringToFront()` in opening method.

So I think this may be a solution.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this will work, but it's worth a try.  Call
[setDescendantFocusability(ViewGroup.FOCUS_BLOCK_DESCENDANTS)](http://developer.android.com/intl/zh-CN/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#setDescendantFocusability(int)) on your container View (the one that the sliding drawer slides over).